# Creating models/database Django FK

Tags: python, mysql, django-models

I’m a student bachelor ICT and currently making a simple webapp. I have no experience with python and django, so im struggling a bit.

I have a running empty MARIADB in a Linux Kali VM.

I have made a ERD from my web app in visual paradigm. I exported the .dll and created the database in MySQL workbench. I used inspectdb to import the django/python code for my models.py.

So far so good.

Django offers the User module, so i didn’t make an own user class 
(auth_user).

The problem is: How do I build the relation with the auth_user class between a class i created called “case”? It’s asking for a default FK value and i have no idea what i means... I googled everywhere, but just “don’t understand”.

- “Class case“ i want to set a relation with a user class. Explanation: A user can create one or more Cases.
- “Class item”. A case can have or more Items (under investigation).

The error I am receiving when declaring a FK in Class item with Case:

“You are trying to add a non-nullable field 'zaakid' to gegevensdrager without a default; we can't do that (the database needs something to populate existing rows).

Please select a fix:

1) Provide a one-off default now (will be set on all existing rows with a null value for this column)

2) Quit, and let me add a default in models.py“

Default value!? I just want a row in Class Item referring to the Case primairy key ID. I have no clue what the default should be...

Example of the code: 
class Case(models.Model):

```
registratienummer = models.CharField(db_column='Registratienummer', unique=True, max_length=10, validators=[RegexValidator(r'^[0-9]{10}$')])

onderzoeksname = models.CharField(db_column='Onderzoeksnaam', blank=False, max_length=255)

Made_by = models.ForeignKey('AuthUser', db_column='Aangemaakt Door', null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
```

class Item(models.Model):

```
merk = models.CharField(db_column='Merk', max_length=255)

type = models.CharField(db_column='Type', max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)

serienummer = models.CharField(db_column='Serienummer', max_length=255, blank=False)

imei = models.CharField(db_column='IMEI', max_length=15, blank=True, null=True, validators=[RegexValidator(r'^[0-9]{15}$')])

#gegevensdrager_soortsocode = models.ForeignKey('GegevensdragerSoort', models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='Gegevensdrager_SoortSoCode') 

#zaakid = models.ForeignKey('Zaak', db_column='Zaak_referentie', on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
```

After that I tried the inspectdb > models.py. This works but I want to add constraints etc, but it doesn’t work for some reason. It’s giving me all kinds of traceback I can’t explain. But first things first, my post is long enough. Hope someone can help me out a bit, since I’m quite stressed out at the moment.

With kind regards, 
Florus.

Comment: Are there already Case items populating your database? This may be happening because it needs a default value to assign to them, since they're already in the database.

Comment: Hi Brendon, yes the import User classes from Django itself. 
For the rest: no. It raised these errors after I set up a fresh db. I wanted to test, creating the dbs directly from Django. 

At this moment I created the db in sql workbench. I didn’t add a user Class because Django gives me those. But I can’t add the auth_user to the case and notes class. Any tip on how to?

Comment: Oh it might be that I first created two columns of case... and then wanted to add th me foreign key??

Comment: That's my thought, if two cases that already exist, they don't have the foreign key associated with them, so it may want a default to provide the existing cases

Comment: Yes, that’s it. Sometimes it’s an easy answer.

Comment: I'm going to drop it as an answer below then, thanks

Answer (score 0):

If the database is already populated with data and you add a new field to that data, then Django needs something to assign to the data already in the database. In this case, you had data that didn't already have a foreign key associated with them, so the requested default is what the program should automatically associate with the previous data.

If you remove the data from your database, this should run normally, or you can give it data to populate those Cases with and manually change it later.